# Invoking a C executable with two parameters from a Script

Tags: c, bash, busybox

I want to invoke a C executable with two arguments both of type string from a script. Am working with busybox shell. There is a script that is called whenever a USB device is plugged. Now I want to invoke my C executable from that script. I tried calling it with `/usr/bin/myExecutable param1 param2 &` but no use. It is not being called. How can I invoke the C executable from the busybox shell script?

Comment: Pretty much the whole operating system is made up of C executables, so `myExecutable` should be no different.  Does the executable exist?  Can you invoke it interactively?

Comment: Did you put the executable in /usr/bin and does it have the right permission bits?

Comment: Did you compile that C source code (which you cannot execute per se) to build an ELF executable? Did you install that executable? Where (in `/usr/bin`, or `/usr/local/bin/`, or elsewhere)? You might heed to call it with the entire file patch, and you should check its permissions.

Comment: Hi all,Thanks for your response.I have the executable in /usr/bin which is an ELF executable.I tried to execute the same executable manually it works fine but through the script it is not invoked.

Comment: OK, so post the script.

Comment: case "${ACTION}" in                                                        
        add)                                                                       
# Create mountpoint and mount the sd device                        
   if mkdir -p /media/${MDEV} && ! mountpoint -q /media/${MDEV}; then 
    mount /dev/${MDEV} /media/${MDEV}/*Here I want to call my executable*/

Comment: Are you sure that this script is called ?

Comment: yes.Its the script called whenever an USB is plugged/unplugged on my target.When an USB is plugged-in it mounts the device to /media.After mounting I want to call a C executable that acts as a DBus-service.This script is in /lib/mdev and my C executale is in /usr/bin.When I try to call the same executable with another script,it works fine and the client receives the signal as expected.But not from the script that I had posted.Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There could be many reasons behind this. I mean what myExecutable program does. Does
it print something on the standard output(terminal)or this program is written to do
some background job.

In any case we can check the status of the last command executed under shell. shell 
store the information in the special variable $?. If the last command was successful
it would return 0 otherwise it would return >0.

If possible, please share the output of the following command from your machine.

$/usr/bin/myExecutable param1 param2 &

$echo $?

Comment: Hi mantosh4u,thanks for the response.My executable works as expected.Yes,the executable has "printf" statements.echo $? prints 0